# Dependency property: Naming convention --> What for?

Tags: wpf

There is a naming convention to call the DependencyProperty *xyzProperty* for a property *xyz*.

- Is this just convention or does WPF behave differently if that naming convention is violated?
- If it's not just convention: Isn't C# used that way moving towards a scripting language like TCL where everything is a string?

Comment: It's a convention which helps to find the `public static` identifier field in case someone wants to call `AddOwner` on your property.

Comment: When you change the static DependencyProperty `xyzProperty` declaration to `xyzWhateverYouWant`, your code is likely to behave the same. You _can_ do that as long as you know what you're doing (sometimes I don't) But that also means everyone using your code should be aware of that _own way of naming things_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this just convention or does WPF behave differently if that naming
>   convention is violated?

No, all code is compiled and Xaml parsed and linked so there is no difference in the resulting WPF. Feel free to name your properties in any way.

Coding conventions are simply to make all developers adhere to a system which may or may not lend itself to more maintainable code; hence its target audience is developers and not the end system.

> If it's not just convention

I have been working professionally in WPF/Silverlight/WP Xaml since its inception and frankly have never come across that convention actually used.

> Isn't C# used that way moving towards a scripting language like TCL where everything is a string?

No. C# is not moving that way because it was designed *from the ground up* to be procedural language and not a functional language. It may take in some things which give it a functional air, but it was designed as a procedural language and it cannot simply change its philosophy without abandoning a large chunk of its codebase to achieve that direction.